# Exporting array to CSV ini PHP with special characters

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

Im exporting a php array to csv.

The error is that all special characters are screwed up (e.g.: á é ñ), and the start of the file displays **ï»¿field1** instead of **field1**.

The issue is happening because of **Content-disposition: attachment;**, if I comment that line, the file is created without any issues (sadly it is downloaded as **FILENAME**.php extension).

```
    # CSV headers
    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-type: application/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.date('Y-m-d H\hi').'.csv');

    # Columns
    $o = 'field1,field2,field3,field4';
    $o .= "\n";

    # Data
    $rows = array();
    foreach($data as $item) {
        $fields = array();
        foreach($item as $field) {
            $fields[] = $field;
        }
        $rows[] = implode(', ', $fields);
    }
    $o .= implode("\n", $rows);
    echo $o;
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You should consider using double-quotes around the filename: `filename="'.date('Y-m-d H\hi').'.csv"'` Also, why are you setting two different content types?

Comment: Im working in Sublime2 (osx). The file is utf-8, without BOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Dagon, ï»¿ is the BOM and may be causing problems with the file being read (specially if it is done in CMD on Windows). Remove the BOM from your script file.

As for the special characters, you may need to convert them, specially if your source isn't UTF-8.

I had a similar problem once and the solution for me was to certify that the input was being read correctly and converting them  before outputting.

For converting the characters, I did something like this:

```
mb_convert_case($result['products_name'], MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8");
```

To certify I was working with UTF-8, I issued

```
$connection->set_charset("utf8");
```

when connecting to my database.

Take care.

Comment: Hi! Im working in Sublime2 (osx). The file is utf-8, without BOM. The mysql charset is also utf8. If i don't force the download with content-disposition, the chars are fine.